# "blank" audio for a AVCaptureSession while on a call

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I have an `AVCaptureSession` utilizing 2 `AVCaptureDeviceInput`'s. The first is `AVCaptureDevicePositionFront` and the second is `[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio]`.

This works great normally, but when I am in a call, the microphone is in use (obviously). **Is there any way to apply a "blank" audio track to the `AVCaptureSession`**? I can use some other work around if need be, but integrating with the `AVCaptureSession` would be good because then all my current code can stay as it.

I have tried subclassing `AVCaptureDevice` and always returning `YES` for `supportsAVCaptureSessionPreset:`, but that was a predictable fail.

The video is streamed in realtime (via RTMP) to the server, so adding the audio in afterwards isn't really an option. Adding in the audio in the nginx RTMP server doesn't seem realistic, so I am hoping to solve this on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a server side solution.

The server had to send an initial audio packet along with the initial video packet.

For what it is worth, I am using [`nginx-rtmp-module`](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module). [This commit](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/commit/36002359c21a546518286e284acb80f9e8276198) is the specific commit that fixed my issues.